# NET Core install runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

In .NET Core rc-1 I can install many different runtimes and manage them with `dnvm` util. In NET Core 1.0 there is no `dnvm`, so the only way to install runtime - download installation packages from [microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)? It is very confusing.

So I now can't install different versions of .NET runtime (maybe use some previous version). How can I update runtime when new versions will be available? Can I download and install previous versions?

Comment: With core you have a choice to include the runtime with your app or install it to `Program Files`. What exactly is confusing here? (PS The new command line is `dotnet`, no longer `dnvm`)

Comment: Yes, I know about that `dnvm` is gone and this is that what make me ask this question. How can I include runtime with my app?

Comment: Everything is a Nuget package, you include the runtime in the same way you include any package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .NET Core 1.0 you can install multiple SDK and runtime versions side-by-side on your system.  In RC1, you could specify which runtime version would be used with the `dnvm use` command.  This is now down with a `global.json` file in your project folder instead (See [global.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json)).

Example `global.json` file specifying SDK version `1.0.0-preview2-003156`:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003156"
  }
}
```

Running any of the new `dotnet` commands from a folder where a `global.json` file is present in that folder (or any parent directory of that folder) will cause the SDK version specified in that file to be used to execute the `dotnet` command.  Each SDK version that you install also installs one of the runtime versions with it.  The version that is actually used by your application is defined in your `project.json` file (or your `.csproj` file if you're using the preview3 or preview4 tools).

If you want to install other runtime versions that are not packaged with the most recent versions of the tools, Microsoft is keeping an archive list of older SDK and runtime downloads [in their GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md).